# Does QED have engineering applications?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, applied-physics

QED is certainly important for understanding the physical World; I'm wondering though, does it has any practical, engineering applications?

For example, is it sufficient for development of lasers to understand QM (for excitation/emission) and classical EM/optics (for the rest), or one needs QED at some points?

Any other applications?

Comment: Positrons. Anti-particles.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski, apart of Asimov's fiction I'm not aware of any engineering applications involving positrons.

Comment: Storage rings for electrons are frequently used with positron fill, because there is an effective cooling mechanism for positrons, and the beam decay rate is smaller for postitrons than electrons.   So, synchrotron radiation labs use a positron beam.

Comment: @Michael https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography